# How do I get values from CIRowAverage filter?

Tags: swift, macos, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to use Apple's `CIRowAverage` `Core Image` filter to compute the average value per row of an image. When I run the filter and try to read out the values, I don't get the average at all: from what I can tell where ever a row has a value, it returns 255 and where ever a row has no values (i.e., all 0's), it returns 0.

So, am I using `CIRowAverage` wrong or did I misunderstand how it is use?

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
let row = ciimage.applyingFilter("CIRowAverage", parameters: ["inputExtent": CIVector(cgRect: ciimage.extent)])

let width = Int(ciimage.extent.width)
let height = Int(ciimage.extent.height)
let bufferSize = width * height * 4
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context = CGContext(data: &buffer, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)!
let ciContext = CIContext(cgContext: context, options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: colorSpace, kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false])
ciContext.draw(self, in: self.extent, from: self.extent)
return buffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I *think* you're correctly reading what the filter does. I've never used it (or any reduction filter) but I think you may be using the *one pixel output* wrong.

Try rendering the output this way:

```
// I'm assuming you are passing a single row here but your ROI suggests maybe not

let row = ciimage.applyingFilter("CIRowAverage", parameters: ["inputExtent": CIVector(cgRect: ciimage.extent)])

// Create a CIContext, then a CGImage, and finally a UIImage

let ciCtx = CIContext()
let cgImage = renderContext.createCGImage(row, from: ciimage.extent)
let uiImage =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

You didn't post code to indicate what `climate.extent` is or what `self` is, so keep these things in mind:

- The input ROI should be - I think - a row of an image.
- The output is *only* one pixel high by the size of `inputCount`.
- Creating `CIContexts` is a very expensive thing to do, so try to create only one.
- If you are trying to end up with a *single* image of *each* row's average color, alter your code (and mine) accordingly.

NOTE: Remember that CoreImage has it "origin" in the bottom left, not upper left. That is, where something like UIKit or CoreGraphics address the X/Y of 0,0 to be the top left, CoreImage addresses 0,0 as the bottom left.

Comment: Small correction: the output is 1px tall and <height of the input> wide. 
Also, it seems to start at the bottom instead of the top, so the first (leftmost) pixel in the output is the average color of the bottom row in the input.

Comment: @YourMJK, thanks for the corrections. I will edit.